# how to change the default back ground color of a form field

Tags: html, css

this is my form (Yii2)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Login') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), 
        ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

when i run this i get a form with a yellow background. i want a white background. so i used the following css

```
background-color: white !important;
```

but it didn't work. user agent stylesheet has this value

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill {
background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);
background-image: none;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

i think this value is the one which causes yellowish color to my form. but i changing it with white didn't solve my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same selector that the User Agent stylesheet uses to overwrite the value in your own CSS:

`input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill { background-color: white; }`

Otherwise it won’t work, if your selector (which you failed to show us btw.) is less specific.

---

Something else you might want to consider though:

This special formatting is used to indicate to the user that they have actually saved login data for this form in their browser’s password manager. Therefor taking this important visual clue away from them for simple “aesthetic” reasons might not be the smartest choice here.

Comment: well i tried but even then i am getting the yellowish bg-color

Comment: Well then show us what exactly you have tried – and preferably also a live example, so that we can see for ourselves were the actual problem lies. Without that, we can’t possibly tell you what might be wrong about your approach, or where you have placed the code.